# Static variable and parameter having the same name

Tags: java

Consider the following code:

```
public class myclasss {
   private static int somevar;

   public setSomeVar(int somevar) {
     somevar = somevar;
   }
}
```

Obviously the code `somevar = somevar;` does not make sense. Is it possible to set the variable `somevar` to `somevar` without changing the parameters name? (i.e. differentiate between the two variables)?

Comment: Aside: setting a static variable in an instance method is confusing. Make `setSomeVar` `static`.

Comment: @AndyTurner not only weird but some static code analysis tools report it as a possible bug.

Comment: @lealceldeiro I (heart) static analysis tools.

Comment: It was only a code snippet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, qualify the name of the static variable:

```
myclasss.somevar = somevar;
```

Similarly for an instance variable:

```
private int anothervar;

public setAnothervar(int anothervar) {
  this.anothervar = anothervar;
}
```